# Xamarin Forms In App Billing plugin does not work

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I installed the in app billing plugin in my Xamarin Forms project: [Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin).

First I want to use it on iOS but the plugin doesn't work. It shows following error: `Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions.InAppBillingPurchaseException: Cannot connect to iTunes Store
  at Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.PurchaseAsync (System.String productId, Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions.ItemType itemType, System.String payload, Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions.IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase verifyPurchase) ..`

I think my productId or the payload is wrong, what should I put in there?
Here is my Code:

```cs
          try
            {
                var productId = "mySKU";

                var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();

                if (!connected)
                {
                    //Couldn't connect to billing, could be offline, alert user
                    return;
                }

                //try to purchase item
                var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.Subscription, "payload");
                if (purchase == null)
                {
                    //Not purchased, alert the user
                }
                else
                {
                    //Purchased, save this information
                    var id = purchase.Id;
                    var token = purchase.PurchaseToken;
                    var state = purchase.State;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                //Something bad has occurred, alert user
            }
            finally
            {
                //Disconnect, it is okay if we never connected
                await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
            }
```

I hope anybody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the issue [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/243) to see if there is any help.

Comment: I saw that I haven't deposited a credit card at all. I think this is my problem I will do that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, you can share your solution in the answer once you solved it which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: I activated it, but it didn't work. If I activate the "In App Purchase" in the Entitlements.plist file, it provides. After that when I close the file and open it again. the "In App Purchase" isn't longer activated. I think this is my problem. 
After the automatic provides it creates a certificate in the App Store Connect. I selected it at the ID. After I clicked save, it changes back to the other certificate that I created. Which one should I use? And what is the "payload" from the InAppBilling plugin.

Comment: I fixed it, I will post it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. For all those who have the same problem: My problem was, that I created a bundle id. Then I activated the automatic signing in Visual Studio and it created another bundle id automatically. I selected it and I had to give it a name. After I clicked save, it changed back to the other id. The problem was that the ids had the same name. So I renamed the bundle id in Visual Studio and it works like a charm.

Comment: Could you add screenshot or step by step how you fix it? It would be great for our community.

Comment: I just completely recreated the App Store entry. You can follow [this](https://youtu.be/fkBRXzotbzw) tutorial (but without uploading the app). Then it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must setup ios settings before using that nuget:

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev88ff319e7

Comment: I activated the automatically manage signing with the right team and I adjusted the bundle Id in Visual Studio. It still shows the error..

Comment: I saw that I haven't deposited a credit card at all. I think this is my problem I will do that. Thanks anyway.